# How to set auto complete input box data on load?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-places-api

I am working on a project into which there is a requirement of setting a text input data on ngInit() of the parent component.

Basically I have a component, which is a Google AutoComplete dropdown, and I have the main HTML page in which I am populating this component.

How can I set a value from the main page who is calling this component?

I am following the source code which is exactly the same as [This Tutorial](https://medium.com/@dhormale/use-google-places-api-autocomplete-using-angular-for-resident-and-office-address-23cc33078e8).

Here I have an `AutocompleteComponent` which is responsible to display the place in a dropdown. And this 
is loaded from `app.component.html`.

I want to set some value to `AutoCompleteComponent` `addresstext` input text box from `app.component.ts`. May be from `ngInit()` of `app.component.ts`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @Input Property of Angular which sends data from Parent Component to Child Component

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction